# delete tableviewcell via button in that specific cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegation

My code below uses a tableVIEWVIEW cell to display a single button. What I want to do is have the button in tableVIEWVIEW cell named deleteBTN delete that specif tableview cell and only delete that cell. I don’t know what class  I should Put the delete in. This probably uses delegation to delete from that specific cell.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var numberOfRows = 3

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { numberOfRows }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 118 }

    var tableView = UITableView()
    var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setTableVIew()
    }
    

    func setTableVIew(){
    
             view.addSubview(box2)
         
             box2.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
             
             
    
       
        
        let VCframe = view.frame
        let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
            let height2 = VCframe.height * 0.2
        let widthx = VCframe.width

        
        
             tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: widthx - 20, height: height)
          
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
        box2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(lease), for: .touchDown)

        tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.press.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.press.addTarget(self, action: #selector(importPhoto), for: .touchDown)
        return cell
    }

 
}
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
      let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
      view.backgroundColor = .green
      print(self.frame.width)
          return view
      }()
      

      
      override func layoutSubviews() {
         backView.clipsToBounds = true
         backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
   

      }


    lazy var deleteBTN : UIButton = {
        let press = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 3, width: 65 , height: 50))
        press.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        press.setTitle("DELETE", for: .normal

        return press
    }()

 

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
        backView.addSubview(deleteBTN)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add that same as you are adding press button target

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.press.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.press.addTarget(self, action: #selector(importPhoto), for: .touchDown)
        cell.deleteBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteCell), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I want to be able to delete each cell in a specific order. That will not work because it is just going to delete the cell lowest on the tableview.

Comment: No ... you need to make indexpath from button tag ?

Comment: what do i put in the @objc func deleteCell?